# Restore app data backup without access to usb debugging

Tags: applications, backup, usb-debugging

Google backup didn't work, and I tried Helium, but you have to connect to usb debugging in order to "enable" it. I have access to usb debugging on the phone i'm backing up, so I have the data, but my new phone only came with a usb-c to usb-c cable, and I can't get a usb-c to usb-a cable for a few more days, but I need my phone to be set up much sooner than that.

Is there any way I can restore that app data in my current situation?

Comment: Are you trying to move data from one phone to another? Or are you trying to turn on USB Debugging? Your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Move data. I have .ab files I've moved from one phone to another, and I need to restore those files on the new phone. I need to know if that's possible without using adb/Helium because I don't have a USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Since *.ab is an Android adb backup file you will have to do it via adb, but since you don't have the correct cord you will have to do it wirelessly.

**Instructions to setup wireless adb:**

1. Download [WiFi ADB - Debug Over Air](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en) and install
2. Turn on your wifi and connect your phone and your computer to the same network.
3. The app will run you through the rest of the setup process.
4. Once setup try "adb devices" , if this works then you are connected and you'll be able to restore the way you normaly do via adb (but wirelessly).

Hopes this helps you overcome your problem of no cord.

Comment: In the description of that app, I read "*This app works on ROOTED devices only.*". I don't see where OP mentioned that the device is rooted. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Yeah, my phone isn't rooted :/ No problem though, Amazon finally shipped my cable and it's coming in today so it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: @Firelord Forgetting to mention about ROOT was a stuff up on my part
And samwill Good  Luck with your phone.